# Mockito: test method that uses only local variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have following method of `MyRestService` class:

```
public Address getOfficeLocation(String id){
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient(tokenOauthUrl);
    String url = String.format(officeAddress, id);
    JSONObject jsonObject = restClient.get(url, null, credentials);
    return AddressParser.parseOfficeAddress(jsonObject);
}
```

I would like to `restClient.get` was called. I wrote following test:

```
@Mock
private MyRestService myService;
@Mock
private RestClient restClient;

@Test
public void getOfficeLocationTest(){
    myService.getOfficeLocation(any(String.class));
    Mockito.verify(restClient, Mockito.times(1)).get(any(String.class), any(MultivaluedMap.class), any(Credentials.class));
}
```

I guess this is complitly wrong approach. I get test failure: `Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

How can I make my method testable?

Comment: You'd need to change your `MyRestService` code to allow dependency injection, basically - our `RestClient` is the dependency there.

Comment: Did you inject the mock `restClient` into `myService` mock? In any case, you're violating the black box testing principle. Better to write a separate test for `RestClient`, imho.

Comment: Your code does not use your mocked version of RestClient since you create a new instance of it

Comment: You need to mock the `RestClient` *class*. There are a number of ways  you can go about this. That said, this is one reason why DI/IoC is a good thing. See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mocking-itweet-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SUT should be something like this

```
class YourClass {
    @Inject
    private RestClient restClient;    //Injecting RestClient

    public Address getOfficeLocation(String id){
        String url = String.format(officeAddress, id);
        JSONObject jsonObject = restClient.get(url, null, credentials);
        return AddressParser.parseOfficeAddress(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

And your test code has

```
@Mock
private MyRestService myService;
```

I believe that MyRestService is your System under test(SUT), so it shouldn't be mocked and instead, a new object of it must be created

Maybe something like

```
@InjectMocks
private MyRestService myService;
```

This will inject the mocked `RestClient` into `MyRestService`

Comment: It probably *should*, because DI/IoC has other benefits as well as testing, but it's not a *must*.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree. But from the OP's test code, it(RestClient) is an object that is to be injected

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in multiple comments. But you can still test the code as-is using Mockito.

Comment: @DaveNewton True. But he cannot assert that the `get` method of `RestClient` is called unless PowerMock or EasyMock is used (If we are using new operator)

Comment: Only if you're not going against an interface, IIRC, but otherwise yes, I think you're correct.